# Forcing a callback function to occur on another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using this proprietary 360 viewer — http://truview.ortery.com/ImageCreator/SampleWeb/HTML5Viewer_cylindrical.html

It’s not responsive and all the JS it runs in obfuscated/encoded so I cannot modify it.

I want to run JS after it’s happened to remove the inline style declarations it adds so that it becomes responsive.

This is the JS I need to run after the viewer has initialised

```
jQuery('.animateCreatorContainer, .animateCreatorPhoto').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

To force that as a callback, you have to be in control of the flow of execution. In order to do that, the 360 viewer needs to know that it has to execute a callback after its completed whatever it needs to complete.

In other words, you have to code the 360 viewer so that it'll call a callback. You limited options:

- Don't use that library
- Modify the library code

This is only if the 360 viewer operates asynchronously, or at a point when you cannot determine the exact time the code execution is happening.

Normally, to force synchronistic flow of execution, you'll just put your calls one right after the other:

```
doSomething();

doSomethingElse();
```

Anything that occurs in `doSomethingElse` that can modify elements acted on by `doSomething` will do so. So that's your third option (making sure you remove the `style` attribute only after you know the 360 viewer code has executed.)

Comment: Thanks… I tried executing after but it basically seems to happen before `animate360()` has finished and so the viewer fails completely… whereas if i leave out that `removeAttr` line… then load page and manually strip it out of the loaded DOM then I get what I want. I might just build my own 360 viewer :D